# Media queries and jquery ".slideToggle()" change the visibility of li elements on resize

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have created a responsive navbar design which seems to work well at first, but I stumbled upon this weird bug where it changes the visibility of the ul elements once you press the hamburger menu icon in mobile view and upscale the viewport to the large breakpoint. You can find it in [this pen](https://codepen.io/Szelmat/pen/MQxevW).

This is the javascript (JQuery) behind it:

```
"use strict";
$("#one").click(function(event) {
 $("#dropdown-1").slideToggle();
 $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
 $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#two").click(function(event) {
 $("#dropdown-2").slideToggle();
 $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
 $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#three").click(function(event) {
 $("#dropdown-3").slideToggle();
 $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
 $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function() {
 $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
 $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
 $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
});

$('#navicon').click(function() {
 $("#links").slideToggle();
 $("#social").slideToggle();
 $("#social").css("display", "flex");
});
```

This bug works differently according to the state of the menu. If you hide it again and resize the window, the li ements won't appear. If you leave it open, their display property will remain "block".

I tried creating "display: flex;" rules for the desktop brekpoint, but it won't do the job. I hope you can help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to make you `.links` class  `display:flex;` to important as below :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #links,
  #lang,
  #main-nav {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```

And this because in mobile version you set your links to `display:block;` with JQuery and that wreck your design in with > 768 ,

See below working snippet :

```js
"use strict";

$("#one").click(function(event) {
    $("#dropdown-1").slideToggle();
    $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
    $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#two").click(function(event) {
    $("#dropdown-2").slideToggle();
    $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
    $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#three").click(function(event) {
    $("#dropdown-3").slideToggle();
    $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
    $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function() {
    $("#dropdown-1").slideUp();
    $("#dropdown-2").slideUp();
    $("#dropdown-3").slideUp();
});

$('#navicon').click(function() {
    $("#links").slideToggle();
    $("#social").slideToggle();
    $("#social").css("display", "flex");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: #111;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.brand {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#links {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#links li {
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 15vw;
  margin: auto 1vw;
}

#social {
  display: flex;
}

#social li {
  margin: auto 1.2vw;
}

nav a {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.caret {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15vw;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown li {
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
  border-radius: 2%;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
}

#navicon {
  margin: auto 2vw auto 1vw;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social,
  #links,
  .dropdown a {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }

  #social li {
    margin: auto 1.8vw;
  }

  #social,
  #links,
  #dropdown {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #social,
  #links,
  .dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: none;
  }

  #navicon {
    display: flex;
  }

  #main-nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
  }

  #links li {
    flex-basis: 100vw;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  #social li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }

  .main-link {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #links,
  #lang,
  #main-nav {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <div id="main-nav">
    <a href="index.html" class="brand"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
    <button id="navicon" aria-label="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <ul id="links">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="one" class="main-link">Header <span class="caret">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdown-1">
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="main-link">Element</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id = "two" class="main-link">Header <span class="caret">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdown-2">
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="three" class="main-link">Header <span class="caret">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdown-3">
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="social">
      <li id="youtube"><a aria-label="youtube_channel" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-lg"></i></a></li>
      <li id="facebook"><a aria-label="facebook_page" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```